# Como obter o nome das propriedades protegidas de um objeto sem os asteriscos?

Tags: php

É possível obter de forma limpa apenas o nome das propriedades protegidas de um objeto sem conter o símbolo asterisco (*).

```
class Person {
    protected $name;
    protected $age;
}

$person = new Person();

print_r(array_keys((array) $person)); //Array ( [0] => *name [1] => *age )
```

O objetivo seria `Array ( [0] => name [1] => age )`.

Existe alguma função do próprio PHP para isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que a ideia é inspecionar um objeto, faça corretamente com as classes de [`Reflection`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.reflection.php):

```
$reflect = new ReflectionObject($person);
$protected = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);

print_r($protected);
```

O método `getProperties` irá retornar as propriedades do objeto e, como foi definido o parâmetro `ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED`, retornará apenas os que são protegidos.

A saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ReflectionProperty Object
        (
            [name] => name
            [class] => Person
        )

    [1] => ReflectionProperty Object
        (
            [name] => age
            [class] => Person
        )

)
```

Se quer apenas a lista com os nomes das propriedades:

```
array_column($protected, 'name')
```

O que retornaria:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => age
)
```

Comment: Obrigado, excelente resposta!